# How to get a time range in MySQL Select query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, date-range

I'm dealing with a problem I just can't get on with.
Let's say, I get results with a simple MySQL Select query:

```
SELECT date_from.rights, date_to.rights FROM rights
```

Table `rights` keeps records describing users' permissions of the system that they need to access.

The permissions are limited by time values, obviously FROM and TO. If `date_from` or `date_to` is NULL, permission is unlimited (time-wise).

The table rights contains the following data:

date_from  . . . . . . . . . date_to

**2011-05-20 . . . . . . . . . 2011-08-20**
**2011-06-20 . . . . . . . . . NULL**
2011-03-20 . . . . . . . . . 2011-04-20
NULL    .. . . . . . . . . . . . . 2011-01-20

What I realy need to get with a SELECT query is:

date_from . . . . . . . . . date_to

**2011-05-20 . . . . . . . . . NULL**
2011-03-20 . . . . . . . . . 2011-04-20
NULL      .. . . . . . . . . . . . . 2011-01-20

Hope You get what I mean by all this. I just need to GROUP results in order to get as wide range of time-limited permissions as possible where every single date value intersect ;)

I think, GROUP BY clause should do the job, but I just can't find the right formula. Also I would like to avoid Procedures, if possible.

Comment: Your 2 "tables" or examples of what you need your SQL query to do is not descriptive enough about your problem. Please answer these questions: 1. what is your table schema? (what fields are on the table) and 2. give some example data and 3. what should the result-set look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
select *
from rights
where (date_from is null or date_from <= now())
and (date_to is null or date_to >= now())
```

Good luck.

Comment: Alan, thank you for your reply, unofrtunately this is not what i Need. This would be too easy :] and give me a result dependently on current date. But I just need to group results I already have achieved from a SELECT query. I've already have a SELECT query, with certain results given (date_from & date_to), I just need to find a intersection of those results and do the job described in my previous post. ;)